# (LARAVEL 5.8)SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hosting, localhost

Quiero ordenar el ID de los prestamos(Loans) en una consulta que estoy haciendo actualmente.
que es esta:

```
$idLoansIn=DB::table('loans as l')
            ->join('payments as p','p.loan_id','=','l.id')
            ->where('l.estado',false)
            ->whereBetween('p.fecha',[$startDay,$endDay])
            ->distinct('p.loan_id')
            ->get(['p.loan_id']);
```

Cuando lo deseo ordenar pongo la siguiente consulta:

```
$idLoansIn=DB::table('loans as l')
            ->join('payments as p','p.loan_id','=','l.id')
            ->where('l.estado',false)
            ->whereBetween('p.fecha',[$startDay,$endDay])
            ->distinct('p.loan_id')
            ->orderBy('p.monto_abonado','asc')
            ->get(['p.loan_id']);
```

En el localhost me sirve perfectamente y en mi web hosting(Hostgator) me sale el siguiente ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause
>   is not in SELECT list, references column
>   'credito6_creditos.p.monto_abonado' which is not in SELECT list; this
>   is incompatible with DISTINCT (SQL: select distinct `p`.`loan_id` from
>   `loans` as `l` inner join `payments` as `p` on `p`.`loan_id` =
>   `l`.`id` where `l`.`estado` = 0 and `p`.`fecha` between 2019-09-27
>   00:00:00 and 2019-09-27 23:59:59 order by `p`.`monto_abonado` asc)

Comment: Si funciona en localhost es posible entonces que alguna tabla no se haya creado en el hosting y por eso no está funcionando.

Comment: Es un [tema de MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829911/how-to-resolve-order-by-clause-is-not-in-select-list-caused-mysql-5-7-with-sel). Probá agregar `->get(['p.loan_id', 'p.monto_abonado'])`.